# DateTime from a DateTime.date and a TimeSpan

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have 2 fields in a table, one for the date as DateTime, one for the time as Timespan.

I really want to construct a complete DateTime value with these two values, but I'm really struggling. This is what I got:

```
PostThr postThr = _context.PostThrs.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ThrZero == zero && m.ThrText == "SCHEDULED START-"); //this is the row with the specifc value
            DateTime startDate = postThr.ThrDate; //this is the dateTime col
            TimeSpan startTime = postThr.ThrTime; //this is the timeSpan col

            string dateString = string.Concat(startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), "T", startTime.ToString());
            DateTime trafficDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: System.DateTime trafficDate = startDate.Date.Add(startTime);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` directly using [addition operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_addition?view=net-6.0) or the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.add?view=net-6.0) method:

```
DateTime trafficDate=postThr.ThrDate.Date + postThr.ThrTime;
```

Even if this wasn't possible, there would be no reason to convert the DateTime and TimeSpan values to strings, you could use one of the [DateTime constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-ctor(system-int32-system-int32-system-int32-system-int32-system-int32-system-int32)) to pass each element directly.

Generating and concatenating strings is expensive. Strings are immutable so any string operations creates a new temporary string that needs to be garbage-collected. Calculating dates this way for every item in a query result would create a *lot* of temporary strings that would waste RAM and CPU time.